# Android - blurred, freeze text and image in recycylerview on emulator

Tags: java, android, emulation, blur

I don't know is that a serious problem but sometimes on my emulator Pixel 2 when I have open the activity with RecyclerView after a couple of seconds it's getting blurred and freeze like on the screenshot in link below. When I try to scroll it's refreshed and goes back normal. Do you have some ideas about what is happening?

[emulator error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NNuq.jpg)

Comment: Hi! What system do you use? I mean CPU, memory, GPU. It looks like you just use a weak system...

Comment: If you asking about my PC so it's i5, 8gb ram, and 3gb GTX1050. Emulator has 2gb ram.

Comment: The reason may be in your ram size. In my experiance 8 gb is now critical for android developing. Any case, I don't think this freezes will appear in your app, running on a real device ))) 
And one more: if it will suit you, you can migrate to linux-like os, it is more stable and comfortable for coding, but not gaming for sure )))

Comment: thank you for your response. I hope it will not be a problem on a real device including some olds phones with 2gb ram :)